# Exoplayer 2 prevent screen dim on video playback

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have simple player activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.epix.presentation.player.PlayerActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the video is running the screen will dim, I have to tap on the screen for it to get brighter again. I've tried setting `android:keepScreenOn="true"`, this of course does not help because the screen does not turn off it just dims.

Is there a way to prevent screen dimming for happening?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Hope this will help someone.

Setting `setKeepScreenOn` while video playing & buffering only, & allowing screen to sleep when the video is paused/not played/any error happened.

```
playerView = exoPlayerLayout.findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

player.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
```

PlayerEventListener

```
private class PlayerEventListener implements Player.EventListener {
    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        if (playbackState == Player.STATE_IDLE || playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED ||
                !playWhenReady) {

            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
        } else { // STATE_READY, STATE_BUFFERING
            // This prevents the screen from getting dim/lock
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {}

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {}

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {}

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) { }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) { }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity() { }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) { }
}
```

Check the playback states [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/f7ed789fc3841b2536f5629c6bb10f4cb4ee5130/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.java#L346), if you want to modify `setKeepScreenOn` based on your needs.

Comment: Hmm this solution _almost_ works for me, it's weird. I'm playing a video in a DialogFragment once I hit `onStart`, `keepScreenOn` is getting called once the video starts playing, but I still see screen off after 30 seconds. Then when I turn the screen back on, video continues playing, and no longer times out. So it's only working for me when I resume playback. Applying `keepScreenOn` directly to the StyledPlayerView layout DOES work 100%, but I'd like to avoid that because it would keep the screen on even when the video is no longer playing.

Comment: Great solution! If it can help anyone, the method is now replaced with `onPlaybackStateChanged`.

Answer (score 15):

Easiest is to have the keepScreenOn attribute with a value of true in your ConstraintLayout element:

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

You may choose to do this programmatically for instance in the onCreate method of your activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

There is a [page about the topic](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen) of keeping the screen on on developer.android.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I've tried this but the problem is not that the screen is turning of, it is dimming but continues to be on.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. State of the player is what determines if the screen should go dim or not, not if a view is rendered or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you get problem, video view is dimmed on dialog fragment or else. you can use this in attribute:

```
app:surface_type="texture_view"
```

its work for me

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the new Exoplayer Version, this method onPlayerStateChanged is deprecated.
So we can use a new method provide by exoplayer which is onIsPlayingChanged.

```
  public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            playerView.setKeepScreenOn(false);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute keepScreenOn

Your ConstraintLayout
android:keepScreenOn="true"

Add programmatically for instance in the onCreate method of your activity

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);